# Unexpected token u on my JSON data returned through jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to display data that is getting returned to me

console.log(data) shows:

```
{"Data":[[true,true,false],null]}
```

This is data that ultimately are values of 3 checkboxes.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot why I am getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

I gather that u = undefined.   Could I be that I need a **POST** instead?  I already tried not having the **contentType** **commented** out.
Clearly I have **DATA** coming back   is the **$parseJSON(data.d)** an issue?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/GetCheckBox/3521',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                console.log(data);
                //WriteResponses(data);
                var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                WriteResponses(objdata);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });

        //Displays in a Table
        function WriteResponses(allNews) {

            alert(allNews);

            var strResult = "<table><th>Name</th><th>Student ID</th><th>Gender</th><th>Age</th>";
            $.each(allNews, function (index, news) {
                strResult += "<tr><td>" + news.StormOut + "</td><td> " + news.StormOut + "</td><td>" + news.StormOut + "</td><td>" + news.StormOut + "</td></tr>";
            });
            strResult += "</table>";
            $("#divResult").html(strResult);
        }

    });
```

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/  says it is  Valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `console.log(data);` shows

```
{"Data":[[true,true,false],null]}
```

then `data` is a **string** (see below for a possible reason why). Why are you trying to parse **`data.d`**? Strings don't have a property `d`. `data.d` returns `undefined` and `$.parseJSON(undefined)` throws the error you are getting.

Use `$.parseJSON(data)` instead.

---

FYI, Ben is right in so far that setting `dataType: json` makes jQuery parse your JSON automatically. However, given the `console.log` output, it appears that your data is *double encoded*. I.e. the data is converted to JSON first and the result is again encoded as JSON.

That's wrong of course. You should ensure that the data is only encoded once, and then remove the `$.parseJSON` call.

Comment: according to answer of Ben's answer `You don't actually need $.parseJSON. jQuery automatically parses it as JSON because you have specified JSON as the data type (dataType: json,).` which is which

Comment: @Pekka: See my additional note.

Comment: objData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    alert(objData);      -->   [object Object]

Comment: @BrianThornton: Perfect. Then it works. Or are you confused by the output? `alert` converts the value to a string, and the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`. See: `alert({foo: 42});`. `alert` is not a debugging tool. `console.log` is.

Comment: @BrianThornton then felix is right you encoded it twice

Comment: Since my data looks like this  **{"Data":[[true,true,false],null]}**   then how can i actually parse that data in a function?

Comment: I do use console.log mostly..    So if the data is parsed then how can I use a function to then do a  $.each  or something?

Comment: @BrianThornton: Just pass the value to the function? `myFunction(myValue)`. I don't know what you want to do with the data, so it's up to you to figure that part out. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196

Comment: So like now I am calling `WriteResponses(data)`   and that function is giving me   -->   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '32' in {"Data":[[true,true,false],null]}`

Comment: @BrianThornton: it looks you are passing the original string to the function, not the parsed value. You get that error when you are trying to pass a string to `$.each` (or at least so I thought, can't confirm right now).

Comment: How do I get the parsed value?

Comment: @BrianThornton: `$.parseJSON` returns the parsed value (that's what the whole answer is about).

Comment: Yes, but with `objData = $.parseJSON(data);`     results from my function showing  `Name Student ID Gender Age
undefined undefined undefined undefined
`

Comment: @BrianThornton: Well, what else do you expect? When you call `$.each(allNews, ...)` then `index` will be `"Data"` and `news` will be the array `[[true,true,false],null]`. You are trying to access `news.StormOut`, etc, but arrays don't have such a property (proof: `console.log([].StormOut);`), nor does such a property occur anywhere in your data.

Comment: Thx ,  I see that  news[0]  = true,true,false       I guess I should play around with this more to separate it out

Comment: @BrianThornton: That's why I said you need to figure out what to do with the data. Even if you manage to add it to the table, `Name: true` doesn't make a lot of sense (well, I guess it depends on the UI).

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need `$.parseJSON`. jQuery automatically parses it as JSON because you have specified JSON as the data type (`dataType: json,`).

As you can see in your console log, the value of `"Data"` is returned as an array - in fact, a JavaScript array, not JSON, which would be surrounded by quotes, it's a JSON string.

So, just swap that line with something like:

```
var objData = data["Data"];
```

And it should work fine :)

More info at the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: var objData = data.Data;  -->  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: data.Data[0]   -->   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: var objData = data.Data;
                    alert(objData);  -->    shows  "undefined"

Comment: still undefined   with  data["Data"]